# How to set databaseAuthVariableOverride in firebase REST

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Firebase has a feature that allows to initialize the connection with a custom auth variable.

linke in example:

```
# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')

# Initialize the app with a custom auth variable, limiting the server's access
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com',
    'databaseAuthVariableOverride': {
        'uid': 'my-service-worker'
    }
})
```

I am using c#, what hasn't a SDK for the language .... I chose to use REST API, but I didn't find in documentation how I can use the feature like in the code above.

There is a way to use databaseAuthVariableOverride in REST for Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is only available in the Admin SDK for the Firebase Realtime Database, which is supposed to run in trusted environments.

If you're using another SDK or the REST API, it won't be available, since it would be a major security risk if users could set their own UID.

If you're calling the REST API from a trusted environment, you could [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) for that call, which would essentially give you the same result.